# (ASP.NET User control) - problems setting properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am creating several .NET User Controls and I am trying to figure out the best way to go about setting properties. I have an address control and I am trying to create a property called ShowCountry which will either hide or show the control's country ddl.

I have been trying to set most of my properties similar to the below code:

```
public bool ShowCountry
{
    get { return (bool)ViewState["ShowCountry"]; }
    set
    {
        ViewState["ShowCountry"] = value;
        pnlCountry.Visible = value;
    }
}
```

How would I set a default value for this property? When I run my page with the control on it, it instantly errors out in the "get{}" when ShowCountry is used in one of my functions because I never set ShowCountry="false" in the control's tag. If I set this property when declaring the control everything works fine.
Also is what I am doing with the ViewState a good way to keep property values across postbacks?

Could someone show me how they would write this property?
**The specs are:**
Must keep value across postbacks, Must default to false

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in order to avoiding error..

```
 public bool ShowCountry
    {
        get {

             if(ViewState["ShowCountry"] != null ){
               return (bool)ViewState["ShowCountry"];
             }
             else { 
               //return the default value
               return false; 
              }
         }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ShowCountry"] = value;
            pnlCountry.Visible = value;
        }
    }
```

i think view state is best approach alternatively you can use hidden field in order to save value against post back.